# ClientAbortException: java.net.SocketException:Broken pipe

Tags: java, soap, tomcat5.5

There is a web application in which SOAP request is sent and its SOAP response is recieved. 
What happening is after getting SOAP response successfully, we are trying to include the display page through below code:

```
1. RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher(uri);    
2. rd.include(request, response);
```

where uri is the location of the display page.

In second line, exception is coming

```
ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException:Broken pipe
```

Any idea what is wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

This occures due to client disconnection. There could be several reason for that like timeout, internet connection broken, browser closed, server refused to accept request because of load etc. In 99% case this exception should be ignored.